Designing a balance's system in DDD using Event-Sourcing
I'm developing a driving-school application inside which students can reserve lessons by spending credits. Hence, students have a credit's balance.
I want to represent this balance using event-sourcing for which I'll basically have two events : credit-added and credit-spent.
Reserving a lesson will be the bulk of the complexity because we must ensure :

The student's availability for the day of the reservation
The monitor's availability the same moment
The credit's balance

At the end of the day, if everything goes well, a Lesson Aggregate is created.
My questions are related to the management of the credit's balance.

How can I know if the student has enough credits ? Should I load & apply all the events every time the student tries to make a reservation or should I keep a snapshot ?
And how should I design that snapshot ? To be always consistent every time a credit is added / spent or to be eventually consistent and hence admit the snapshot might (although very unlikely) be a little off by the time the lesson is reserved ? Which would imply developing a form of verification & compensation (and increase complexity a lot).

I don't think the balance will contain a lot of events. In the lifetime of the student, we can safely say there will be at most a few hundred events.

This question looks more suitable for a design discussion.  You might get better feedback from the ddd-cqrs-es discord: https://discord.gg/sEZGSHNNbH



How can I know if the student has enough credits ? Should I load & apply all the events every time the student tries to make a reservation or should I keep a snapshot ?


That depends on scale. If there aren't many such events, then you don't need snapshots. But it is likely that at some point these will be necessary, so I suggest you implement them straight away.


And how should I design that snapshot ? To be always consistent every time a credit is added / spent or to be eventually consistent and hence admit the snapshot might (although very unlikely) be a little off by the time the lesson is reserved ?


Eventual consistency has advantages and disadvantages. The biggest advantage is that it scales well. The biggest disdvantage is that some users may go into negative balance. Meaning they can spend more than they actually have.
This is hard to fix. If a user goes into a negative balance and buys a lesson, then what kind of compensation can fix that? None. It is likely the user will go through the lesson (at least partially) before you are able to react. Even if you take away access, it won't matter. It is too late. And if you try to make the system to react fast enough, you will quickly find out that it is hard and complicated. And you will start thinking: why didn't I implement strong consistency from the beginning?
So lets agree that with eventual consistency, if such event occures, then you won't be able to fix it. And it will be loss of money for you. You may try to get the money back from the user, but lets be honest: this is hard, time consuming, there's no success guarantees, and noone wants to do this.
The real question thus is: how often such situation happens? Probably rare enough that you can accept the risk.
Now you say:

Which would imply developing a form of verification & compensation (and increase complexity a lot).

I'm not sure what you mean by "verification", but if you suggest implementing transactional layer manually, then just give up. That is insanely hard to do correctly. And if you mean doing some post-factum verification then the question is when? If your system gives access to the lesson right after payment, then this verification would have to happen at the same time as well. So now you have a system that tries to mimick strong consistency, except in an inefficient and complicated way. And likely incorrectly.
But there's a simpler solution. You say that there won't be many events. If that's the case, then why don't you pick and use any ACID database like MySQL or PostgreSQL? Take advantage of the fact that these provide transactions and strong consistency out-of-the-box. ACID databases are problematic to scale, but honestly, if you don't have the scale of Google or Facebook, or at least a bank, then it doesn't matter. And if you do have such scale, then congratulations, and I'm pretty sure you can afford specialists that will solve that problem for you. :)
In fact this also solves your snapshot problem. You simply keep track of current state in the database and serve it on demand. You can still keep track of events, as a historical data. But that way the design and implementation becomes a lot easier.
